# Record variable to a dummy variable using weekdays

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have a variable that starting from Monday that lists each date from 1-7. I want to change this to weekday vs. weekend, with a 0-1 respectively to create a dummy variable. I know how to do one, but I can't figure out how to include 6 AND 7 in iterations of the code.

For example, I put the following:

```
flights$dayweek <-factor(ifelse(as.numeric(flights$dayweek)==6, 1,0))
```

My intent for the above is for the code to find anywhere it says 6 & 7, then replace it with 1 and anything else is 0 for the variable dayweek in the flights data set. The problem with the above is it only does 6 and NOT 7. I don't know how to include 7 in the data set. I have tried:

```
flights$dayweek <-factor(ifelse(as.numeric(flights$dayweek)==6:7, 1,0))
flights$dayweek <-factor(ifelse(as.numeric(flights$dayweek)==c(6,7), 1,0))
```

And I have looked at other common dummy variables topics, but they all seem to be simple 1 to 0 like male/female and I know how to do that. Could I do a greater than 5 function? Sample data below:

```
schedtime carrier deptime dest distance date dayweek daymonth delay
1700      RU      1651    WER  213      1401    4       1     ontime
1800      RU      1402    EWR  199      1401    6       1     delayed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%in%` operator to test inclusion in a vector.

```
# using an example dataset
flights <- data.frame(dayweek = rep(1:7, 2), "flight" = letters[1:14])
flights$dayweek <-factor(ifelse(as.numeric(flights$dayweek) %in% c(6, 7), 1,0))

> flights
   dayweek flight
1        0      a
2        0      b
3        0      c
4        0      d
5        0      e
6        1      f
7        1      g
8        0      h
9        0      i
10       0      j
11       0      k
12       0      l
13       1      m
14       1      n
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This instead put everything to 0 instead of just changing anything in the column that is 6 or 7 to 1. There are 250 iterations of 6 and 253 of 7 so I should have an output of 503 1s.

Comment: Can you please post an exerpt from your data using `dput`?

Comment: Please add it to the question.

Comment: @Greg , your data and my example dataset look very similar. Do you still have a problem with the solution provided?

Comment: Aha! It worked. So this is my second day of R. I will have to study up on %in%. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What if I want to recode the carrier to 1 or 0. So the above code has RU, but I want it to say 1. Does that mean I use the same code but just in quotes?

Comment: @Greg Yes, something like `ifelse(flights$carrier == "RU", 1,0)`, or if you want to code, say, AA also to 1: `ifelse(flights$carrier %in% c("AA",  "RU"), 1,0)`. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked too. It is the checkmark, right? Sorry, I am new.